# Problems with UIStoryBoard and Custom SplashView

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, splash-screen, uistoryboard

As with ios4 i can create my custom view for showing as splash screen and can set rootViewController in appdelegate file using xib

but

with iOS 5 with UIStoryBoard how to set or change default UIStoryBoard to first show the Splash Screen and then the required view in my app it is one navigation controller

Please help me with this
Thanks in advance

Happy Coding  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution through some research have to use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` and problem is solved.

No requirement to use any other `UIStoryBoard` just have to put required `UINavigationController`

and it's work like charm

thanks to GOOGLE and Apple

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to present a modal view controller like that:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication*)application
{
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

   dispatch_once( &onceToken, ^
                 {
                    SomeLaunchViewController* launchViewController = [[SomeLaunchViewController alloc] init];
                    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:launchViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
                 } );
}
```

Presenting the view controller modally in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` didn't work for me — the 'UIStoryboard' mechanism seems to be not yet finished at that time.

Using `dispatch_once` ensures that the modal launch screen will only show up once and not every time the application becomes active from being in a background state.

This example uses ARC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will take look at it. And +1 for using block and thread.